# Need help remote connecting to MySQL running on Windows Server!

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mysql

I'm trying to populate a MySQL DB from my computer. I've located the .ini file called "my-medium.ini" which contains a line I was suppose to either remove or uncomment. It's the "skip-networking" line. The client I'm attempting to connect with from my pc requires the host name, db name, username and password. I added the host name, db name, and then added the username and password for my MySQL db. I'm still unable to connect. Is there anything else I need to do with the my-medium.ini file to allow access? I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: You are editing wrong file. `my.ini` is your options file on Windows. Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to view  your firewall which port is opened. If port for sql is closed  your client will still cant cannect